# When is retopology required?

Tags: mesh, workflow

I have a high poly mesh which i would like to texture. Do I need to retopolize it in order to do this? Can I bake maps (for example specularity)straight from the high poly mesh (around 9 mil tris)? I will be rendering an image with no other background objects, just the mesh.[image]

Comment: If you want to deform your mesh then u need to make retopo. And no, Blender is not that slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retopology is required for performance:

- if you need to deform the mesh (armature, etc.)
- if you need to do simulation with the mesh
- if you need to do real-time rendering of the mesh
- if you need to paint very hipoly object (this point is not true for other software than Blender, for example Zbrush can paint high-resolution meshes easily)

Since [Cycles has a shadow terminator limitation](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?351827-Basic-smooth-shading-not-working/) with rendering low-poly objects you need to render a high-enough-poly anyway (subsurf with displacement or normalmap). So depending on the object if you do not need the performance gain from the bullet points above it might be better to render just the highpoly and save time with the retopo work. With decimated hipoly you can get the same vertex count as with retopo+subsurf (so same render time) and you save a displacement or normal map texture space in VRAM/RAM (and some pre-render computation). The color can be either in vertex colors or the decimated hipoly can be unwrapped to use a texture similar as the retopo mesh would. However unwrapping high-poly meshes is slow in Blender (actually everything is slow in Blender with hipoly).

Every object is different, but the general approach would be this:

1. Try decimating the object enough so the poly-count is the lowest but you don't loose detail in render.
2. Next try painting into the vertex colors (you can have multiple of vertex color "textures" for specularity, roughness, color, etc.)
3. If the painting is too slow and you are unable to use other app than Blender for painting the mesh, try unwrapping the decimated mesh (you can use automated unwrap without making seams). If that is also unusable or painting into texture is also slow, you will have to put in the work of retopology to optimize the mesh to increase performance.

Comment: Is there a way to make different parts of a mesh have different specularity without making a specularity map?

Comment: @Otto Yes you can paint the specularity information into vertex colors.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the object, like it does in any other case. If it's an inanimate object, you might want to take the importance in account. Background objects don't need to have necessarily 9 Million triangles and many effects could be achieved by clever texturing and displacement mapping.

There's also a difference between organically shaped objects and hard-surface objects.

Texturing high-poly objects is no fun at all. As Jerryno already said, it's slow and, depending on the method you used to create the object (sculpting, maybe even dyntopo), you might have no clearly visible edge loops. You then might end up with far more seams than you would have with a more organized model. This carries over to texture paint, if you want to get rid of the seams that image textures inevitable produce.

The main advantage of retopologizing objects is the reusability you gain. You can easily go from low to medium to high again.

Comment: Are cavity and normal maps needed on a high poly mesh? And could I apply different specularity on different parts of a mesh without creating any maps or even unwrapping the mesh?

Comment: It depends. Cavity maps come in handy, when the high-poly count still doesn't deliver the amount of detail you want in your model. Normal maps won't be normally necessary as you already have a high-detail object and there's no need to fake more detail through light/shadows. Anyway, it's quite hard to tell without seeing the model.

Comment: I have added a quick render it uses no maps of any kind. Is it possible to texture and add specularity without unwrapping? If I must unwrap, should i use a displacement modifier to add detail to a decimated mesh?

Comment: Looking at your model, it would be quite a hazzle to create a uv-map for it. There are also no visible ridges between the beak and the head for example, where you could split up your mesh into two in order to assign different materials. On the other hand, it would make a really nice base mesh for retopology. You could then bake high-poly to medium poly and yes, I would use a displacement modifier after that. I'd also go for the whole stack, baking normal and AO maps.

Comment: would there be a very noticable difference between a mesh retopolized by hand and one which has had the number of subdivisions reduced (I havent applied the multires modifier yet).

Comment: Retopologizing by hand gives you more control over the areas that probably need a more dense mesh, like the area around the eyes. Your base mesh (without multires) can be vastly different from your hipoly mesh not only in detail. So yes, there probably will be a big difference.