# Extremely stretched faces after extruded in sculpting

Tags: faces, sculpting

[image]I am new to sculpting and I am having a mesh here which I decided to make bigger to create sort of a body out of it, so I locked the upper part of the mesh with B and used the standard brush to extrude the mesh down and now, as seen in the picture the mesh is pretty stretched at one part and not usable for further sculpting.
I'd appreciate if somebody could tell me how to avoid or fix this.

Thanks a lot for the attention and help.

Comment: 29 mln faces? Em.. That's the first reason for the sculpting not going further. Do not subdivide that much that fast, add subdivisions along with adding details. It's hard to tell from the screenshot how is that extrude is made, what is seen is that starting from the detailed part of the bust and down to the bottom faces are heavily stretched, maybe by grabbing with Grab bursh. I'd suggest starting this sculpt from scratch.

Comment: Oh yeah, so much faces could be one reason xD okay, got it, I should approach that much differently xD trying to save what I got but if nothing works I guess I have no choice, thanks :)

Comment: There's a way to retopologize the copy of the mesh while [retrieving details back on the copy](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/04/06/saving-lost-sculpted-details), but you still have to model retopo copy.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, to be honest. Would you explain further?

Comment: There are shown meshes you will have in the end in the video, probably you want to learn what is retopology and [when it's needed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/66212/1245), also https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36525/1245. Generally - you have a sculpted mesh which for some reason can't be left as is (messed up topology, too much of geometry etc.) You create its copy atop of existing sculpt (retopo). There's outlined a way to save details from the original sculpt to the copy using Shrinkwrap using 2 mesh copies; but you have to create that mesh copy first.