# How to apply Curve modifier to the text

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I apply Curve modifier to the text in order to get a simple mesh object?

I can't apply the Curve modifier to the Text object:
[image]

If I will convert the text to mesh (Alt+C - Mesh from the curve) and then apply the Curve modifier - I see some weird triangles on the letters:
[image]

Comment: Related  [How to add curve modifier to text?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text)

Comment: Before conversion modifier can't be applied to the text object. After the conversion you get bad topology (common for text objects) which is visible due to curved angles of the letters. The only way is to retopo the text, preferably prior to applying modifier

Comment: @MrZak That's really sad - is there no other way besides manual retopology?

Comment: After converting to mesh. Select all and delete limited dissolve. Add Mean crease to all edge. Add sub surface modifier

Comment: Why do you want the curved text to be a mesh anyway? I'm not clear on the purpose of this especially since the curved text works perfectly fine as long as you don't convert it to a mesh, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @TeeTrinker For 3D printing

Comment: Likely there isn't - text object and curves will always have that topology after conversion. Retopo though might be done more or less quickly depending on the case. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66212/when-is-retopology-required for some examples, there are some addons like BSurfaces and InstantMeshes as free, RetopoFlow and more as paid.